# How to show mp3 player in django

Tags: python, django

I have a question. I want to have on my website a mp3 player. I made somethink like this:

models.py

```
class Wpisy(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name="Tytuł")
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=400,verbose_name="Przyjazny adres url")
    content = models.TextField()
    status_audio = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name="Czy dostępny będzie plik audio?")
    audio_file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/',verbose_name="Plik audio")
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Data utworzenia")
    category = models.ForeignKey(Kategorie, verbose_name="Kategoria", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and i have also in html file the code :

```
{% extends 'bajki/index.html' %}

{% block content %}
Utworzono : {{detale_bajki.created_date}}<br>
Kategoria: {{detale_bajki.category}}<br>
 {{ detale_bajki.title }}<br>
 {{ detale_bajki.content}}<br><p>
 {% if detale_bajki.status_audio == True %}
 <audio controls>
    <source src="/uploads/{{ audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mp3">
    Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje plików audio.
 </audio>
 {% else %}

 {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

the mp3 player in html is visible on the page but play nothing. In admin mode i'v added a mp3 song in the few of records but still nothing. Also I'v created in settings.py the lines :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
```

Comment: View page source on your browser, what is being displayed as the `src` value for your `audio controls`?

Answer (score 0):

Page source is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Portal z bajkami</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bajki.css">
</head>
<body>
<a href="/bajki/">Strona główna</a> |
<a href="/kontakt/">Kontakt</a> |<br>
</body>
</html>



<br>

Utworzono : 20 stycznia 2018 13:18<br>
Kategoria: Bajki do czytania<br>
 Nieposłuszna owieczka<br>
 na pewnej farmie....<br><p>

 <audio controls>
    <source src="/uploads/How_it_Began.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje plików audio.
 </audio>
```